# Internal Server Error: the server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration!

Tags: apache-2.2

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, gcadmin@pair.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

This has something to do with any htcaccess file or something?

This page works perfectly in my localhost, but when I upload it here: http://globalcolleague.com/test/ it throws the error.

Comment: are there differences between the configuration of the virtualhost in  your localhost and in the server?

Comment: Run: "apache2ctl configtest" and post the results.  Also hit the page the tail your apache log.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start looking is the `error_log`. Take a look at it, it will probably enlight the way.

If the errors logged are not clear enough, use `strace`:

```
strace -f -o strace.output -p pid_of_apache
```

This will output all system calls made by the apache process and its childs (-f flag follows the childs as well) to a file named strace.output. strace is awesome to give some hints on what's going on when the error log is not clear enough.

Hope this helps.